# ¿Como tener un contenedor de mysql que actualize mi db en Docker Hub?

Tags: mysql, docker, contenedores

Soy nuevo con docker, necesito tener un contenedor que este corriendo un servidor mysql, y que al yo modificar los datos de la db, hacer un commit y push a docker hub, mi compañero lo descargue y tenga los mismos datos que yo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero, debes entender que en primera instancia, los datos del contenedor son volátiles, de modo que cuando muere el contenedor, todo se resetea. 
Por tanto, para obtener datos persistentes, debes montar como volumen /var/lib/mysql o el directorio donde tengas los datos de mysql. De ese modo, si el contenedor muere, los datos permanecerán en el volumen.

Luego, tendrás que crear una imagen docker que haga un bind de ese volumen (tendrás que hacer un dockerfile). Una vez subida a tu repositorio, ya se la podrá descargar tu compañero.